# Upload multiple image into different column of database when if has same name

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with core php. I want to upload multiple image as five and insert into databse. I have created five different field that have same name. My code is like :

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="slider_image[]" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Offer Days" required>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="slider_image[]" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Offer Days" required>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="slider_image[]" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Offer Days" required>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="slider_image[]" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Offer Days" required>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="slider_image[]" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Offer Days" required>
<input type="submit" name ="submit">
```

And my php code is like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


$image = $_FILES['slider_image']['name'];


$temp = $_FILES['slider_image']['temp'];

$path = "upload/";

foreach ($image as $key => $value) {
    //echo $value."---";
}
```

output of pirnt_r($image) is :

```
Array(
[0] =&gt; 001.jpg
[1] =&gt; 001.jpg
[2] =&gt; 001.jpg
[3] =&gt; 001.jpg
[4] =&gt; 001.jpg
)
```

And my table name is slider and field's are :

1)id
2)slider1
3)slider2
4)slider3
5)slider4
6)slider5
So how can I insert slider image into different fields when it has the same post name?

Comment: In this case I think it's best to use different `name` attributes

Comment: Treat it like the array that it is? - I'm not sure I understand your issue completely.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_FILES);` at the top of this code. That will show you what the `$_FILES['slider_image']` array actually looks like.

Comment: @RiggsFolly $image print as its key and value.For example array([0]=>image1.jpg [1]=>image2.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question with the output of the `print_r()`

Comment: Have you used the same image in each file field from the form?

Comment: @Epodax yes, i have used the same image.

Comment: I still don't understand the issue, the array has unique keys that allows you to call each image separately as you might want, if you however are referring to the image name, then that's a separate issue as I don't think any file can have the same name in the same location (while being the same file type).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign all array values to local variables and those local variables you can use in sql query.

```
$var1 = Array[0]
$var2 = Array[1]
$var3 = Array[2]
$var4 = Array[3]
$var5 = Array[4]
```

Use these variables in query.

Comment: I have used same as you said. like $image[0]

Comment: So what problem your facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can print `$_FILES['slider_image']['name'];` this it will show you indexing from that you obtain a array and you simulate what you want.